# Regex(tFileInputRegex) unable to Parse Log file in Talend

Tags: regex, logging, talend

Use Case: Need to parse the log file in talend using tFileInputRegex component.

Here is the Google Drive link showing Talend Job

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B70sWgu-vmdRd2ZiNTJOU2tNdDQ

Regex used to parse this file:

```
"^"+
"([0-9]{4}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2})"+" "+
"([0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{3})"+" "+
"(.*?)"+" "+
"\\((.*)\\)"+" "+
"\\[(.*)\\]"+" "+
"(.*)"
```

Below is input file content:

```
2017-05-09 10:18:52.743 INFO  (qtp1543727556-22) [   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [UIMATestCollection1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={}{} 0 66
2017-05-09 10:18:52.745 ERROR (qtp1543727556-22) [   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=1] unknown field 'sentence'
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:82)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:211)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:955)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:736)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.uima.processor.UIMAUpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UIMAUpdateRequestProcessor.java:124)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2306)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-05-10 10:18:52.808 INFO  (qtp1543727556-13) [   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
```

Shared below the Error occured in Talend Job console

```
Starting job Test_1 at 16:32 12/05/2017.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3827
[statistics] connected
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:183)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:82)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:277)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:211)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:166)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:955)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1110)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:736)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.uima.processor.UIMAUpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UIMAUpdateRequestProcessor.java:124)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:250)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:177)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:166)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2306)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:658)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
Line doesn't match:     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:296)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
Line doesn't match:     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
Line doesn't match:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Line doesn't match: 
.----------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|                                                                                                                                                     tLogRow_1                                                                                                                                                      |
|=---------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------=|
|Date      |Time        |Log_Level|App_Thread      |Collection                                                                                              |Message                                                                                                                                                 |
|=---------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------=|
|2017-05-09|10:18:52.743|INFO     |qtp1543727556-22|   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [UIMATestCollection1                      | webapp=/solr path=/update params={}{} 0 66                                                                                                             |
|2017-05-09|10:18:52.745|ERROR    |qtp1543727556-22|   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=1|unknown field 'sentence'                                                                                                                                |
|2017-05-10|10:18:52.808|INFO     |qtp1543727556-13|   x:UIMATestCollection1                                                                                |o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}|
'----------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

[statistics] disconnected
Job Test_1 ended at 16:32 12/05/2017. [exit code=0]
```

The partial output I am getting is as shown below

```
.----------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|                                                                                                                                                     tLogRow_1                                                                                                                                                      |
|=---------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------=|
|Date      |Time        |Log_Level|App_Thread      |Collection                                                                                              |Message                                                                                                                                                 |
|=---------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------=|
|2017-05-09|10:18:52.743|INFO     |qtp1543727556-22|   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [UIMATestCollection1                      | webapp=/solr path=/update params={}{} 0 66                                                                                                             |
|2017-05-09|10:18:52.745|ERROR    |qtp1543727556-22|   x:UIMATestCollection1] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=1|unknown field 'sentence'                                                                                                                                |
|2017-05-10|10:18:52.808|INFO     |qtp1543727556-13|   x:UIMATestCollection1                                                                                |o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}|
'----------+------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current regex? What's the expected output?

Comment: I am able to parse the first row properly

Comment: At the end after error it is displaying partial output .Currently row separator for tFileInputRegex is "\n" so for each line it is considering it has single row.it is ignoring the stack trace in my log file which is more then one line. I want stack trace should go to single last column until it will encounter the next log.

Comment: I don't know talend at all, you will need to find how to do multiline parsing on your own. [This](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=34793) looks like it might help. Speaking from a PCRE point of view, you will likely need the MULTILINE (so that your `^`  anchor matches start of lines instead of just start of text) and DOTALL flags (so that your `.` can match linefeeds). Aside from that is seems about good although you will have to make the last group lazy

Answer (score 1):

Errors said "line doesn't match" because your regex force the line to start by two dates.
You should use a tool like https://regex101.com/ to test your regex for each different cases.

After some test, you need to rework your entire regex to match your other cases.